# gcc fails to compile pjsip 2.7.1. sample c++ code

Tags: c++, pjsip

I am trying to compile with the following Makefile the sample code pjsua2_demo.cpp (renamed as myapp.cpp), provided by pjsip project, however I get the follwoing errors:
The OS is Centos 7..

```
[root@localhost pjsip]# make
cc -o myapp myapp.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`
cc: error: @PJ_INSTALL_CXXFLAGS@: No existe el fichero o el directorio
cc: error: @PJ_LDXXLIBS@: No existe el fichero o el directorio
make: *** [myapp] Error 1


   [root@localhost pjsip]# cat Makefile
    # If your application is in a file named myapp.cpp or myapp.c
    # this is the line you will need to build the binary.
    all: myapp

    myapp: myapp.cpp
                $(CC) -o $@ $< `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`

    clean:
                          rm -f myapp.o myapp
    [root@localhost pjsip]#
```

I could not figure out the way to set these variables, I even tried with pkg_config, as some articles indicate, however it did not work.

```
[root@localhost pjsip]# pkg-config --cflags libpjproject
@PJ_INSTALL_CXXFLAGS@ -I@INCLUDEDIR@  
[root@localhost pjsip]# 

[root@localhost pjsip]# pkg-config --libs  libpjproject
@PJ_LDXXLIBS@ -L@LIBDIR@  
[root@localhost pjsip]# 

[root@localhost pjsip]# pkg-config --version
0.27.1

[root@localhost pjsip]# pkg-config --modversion libpjproject
@PJ_VERSION@
[root@localhost pjsip]# 


[root@localhost pjsip]# env|grep PKG
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/sd/Downloads/pjproject-2.7.1
[root@localhost pjsip]#
```

Would you have any idea?
On the other hand, I followed the follwoing instructions to install pjsip, and I got some errors druing the 'make dep' command (I copied them below). Might this be a problem? I tried disabling the libyuv, however it didn't help. Thanks in advance

```
[root@localhost pjsip]# cd pjproject-2.7.1
[root@localhost pjproject-2.7.1]# ./configure --enable-shared
[root@localhost pjproject-2.7.1]# make dep
[root@localhost pjproject-2.7.1]# make
[root@localhost pjproject-2.7.1]# make install  

make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sd/Downloads/pjproject-2.7.1/pjsip-apps/build'
make -f Samples.mak depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/sd/Downloads/pjproject-2.7.1/pjsip-apps/build'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `depend'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sd/Downloads/pjproject-2.7.1/pjsip-apps/build'
make[1]: se sale del directorio `/home/sd/Downloads/pjproject-2.7.1/pjsip-apps/build'
[root@localhost pjproject-2.7.1]#
```

Comment: The error messages are not in English, so people who don't speak Italian cannot help you. You can get English error messages by something like `export LANG=C` and re-running these commands.

Comment: Hi Jan, sorry, I translated the messages

Comment: [root@localhost pjsip]# make

cc -o myapp myapp.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs libpjproject`

cc: error: @PJ_INSTALL_CXXFLAGS@: The file or the directory does 
not exist

cc: error: @PJ_LDXXLIBS@: The file or the directory does not exist

make: *** [myapp] Error 1

Comment: The original question still contains non-English text.